# NServiceBus Warnings with NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, nservicebus

I've swapped out the RavenDB Persistence for NHibernate, but during startup, I'm seeing the following warning for every assembly:

> 2013-09-24 09:51:41,130 [1] WARN  NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration
>   [(null)] <(null)> - No mapped documents found in assembly:
>   NServiceBus.Transports.SQLServer, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=9fc386479f8a226c

I have no experience with NHB.  Do I need to provide something additional to address these warnings?

Comment: Does it work fine, other than the warning messages?

Answer (score 3):

If everything is working fine other than these warnings, then don't worry about it.  This warning is produced when `Configuration.AddAssembly` is called against an assembly that does not contain any embedded *.hbm.xml mappings.  I believe the purpose of the warning  is to help you figure out what's going wrong in case you completely forgot to mark your mappings as "embedded resource".  It sounds like your application is just looping through every assembly in the application, scanning for NHibernate mappings.  Calling this method on assemblies that don't contain any mappings won't hurt anything other than start-up performance.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your session factory config is not referencing correctly to assemblies.
Adding you config files will help to see the context.